# Lineare Regression: dtype('<M8[ns]') to dtype('float64')

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

I receive the following TypeError:
`TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('<M8[ns]') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'`

The reasons seems to be connected to that part here:
`X = event_data.index.values.reshape(-1,1)`

Do you see what I am doing wrong here? [Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ym8SX2wSFUtHI5bnZd89BCtdHr-IKyK3cqduhsEkdT4/edit#gid=0) a link to my data.

```
from sklearn import linear_model

def load_event_data():
    df = pd.read_csv('sample-data.csv', usecols=['created', 'total_gross'])
    df['created'] = pd.to_datetime(df.created)
    return df.set_index('created').resample('D').sum().fillna(0)

event_data = load_event_data()
event_data['total_gross_accumulated'] = event_data['total_gross'].cumsum()
print(event_data.index.dtype)
event_data.head()

# Explore data
X = event_data.index
y = event_data['total_gross_accumulated']

plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.plot(X, y)
plt.show()

# Create and Fit a Linear Regression Model
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()

# Reshape X
X = event_data.index.values.reshape(-1,1)
regr.fit(X, y)
y_predict = regr.predict(X)

# Show data and prediction
plt.plot(X, y)
plt.plot(X, y_predict)
plt.show()
```